# How to access variables in a fieldset with variable_get

Tags: 7, forms, configuration

```
function bi_mx_enhancement_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['bi_mx_enhancement_government_ws'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Government Web Service Settings'),
        '#tree' => true,
        '#collapsible' => true,
    ];
    $form['bi_mx_enhancement_government_ws']['base_url'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Base URL'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('base_url', 'https://'),
        '#description' => t('The base URL of the Government Web Service for Medic Validation. NOTE: Do not add a trailing slash.'),
        '#required' => true,
    ];

    return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Variable base_url does not get saved, I always get the default value in the form.

I took a look at Drush, and it is like this:

```
bi_mx_enhancement_government_ws:
  base_url: 'http://52.203.204.11:8282/api/medicos'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting #tree to `TRUE`, the values will be saved in the *bi_mx_enhancement_government_ws* persistent variable, which will contain an array. For the code you are showing, its value will be similar to the following one.

```
array(
  'base_url' => 'https://'
);
```

Instead of `variable_get('base_url', 'https://')`, consider using the following code.

```
$values = variable_get('bi_mx_enhancement_government_ws', array());
$ws_base_url = $values['base_url'];
```

When you are now using `variable_get('base_url', 'https://')`, you should use `$ws_base_url`.

Since you seem to just use a single setting for that fieldset, I would rather use `'#tree' => FALSE`, if that form doesn't have any other form field which is using *base_url* as identifier.